# How do I check if a record saved successfully in Django?

Tags: python, django

Could you take a look at this code below?

It seems like the form is submitted and validated successfully. However, it doesn't seem to be saving to my database. Please check my comment in the post() method below starting with #####. I know in PHP one can print_r($var); exit; but can't seem to find equivalent in Python/Django.

```
class ReportListView(ListView):
    model = ReportList
    form_class = ReportListForm
    initial = {}
    context_object_name = 'reportlists'
    template_name = "reports.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #context['now'] = timezone.now()
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    return ReportList.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # process form cleaned data
        # name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')  # .lower()
        new_report = form.save(commit=False)
        new_report.user = self.request.user
        new_report.save()
        
        ### what can I write to check if new report has been saved? 
        ### also, how can I print something here to print that in the browser e.g. 
        ### print(datavariable) 
        ### exit() ?? or something to stop execution here so that I read previous print output

        return redirect('report')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know where the problem is. If you try to print anything from get_context_data() or get_queryset() it's going to fail, because you specified your context in get() method. So both get_context_data() and get_queryset() are not going to be called. In your case what you want to do is to modify your get() method and get rid of two previous methods I mentioned, so your code in get() would look like this:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
    reportlists = ReportList.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'reportlists': reportlists}})
```

Overwriting get() and post() is what would ultimately be the source of your template's content. Now I defined reportlists in your get() method, and sent it via context to the template, so it would be accessed under the name `reportlists` in the template itself. The whole code now could look like this:

```
class ReportListView(ListView):
    model = ReportList
    form_class = ReportListForm
    initial = {}
    template_name = "reports.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        reportlists = ReportList.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'reportlists': reportlists})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # process form cleaned data
            # name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')  # .lower()
            new_report = form.save(commit=False)
            new_report.user = self.request.user
            new_report.save()
            return redirect('report')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: I am using sqlite3 and I can confirm now that saving is working. However, I can't seem to read it. Please take a look at my get_queryset() above.

Comment: Ok, I modified my comment, check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I only realised my mistake 1 min ago and come back here to see that you've spotted the same mistake. I'm new to Django/Python so I didn't realise the context was getting cleared off in the get(). I will update my code and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can check if new_record has an id:

`created = new_record.id`

for instance:

```py
if not created:
    raise  # or other stuff
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried to check created value and it does seem to save it. So saving is working. could you check if my get_queryset() is setup correctly? I want to retrieve a user's reports. The model is name[charfield], user[foreignkey user]. My database is sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

If the save `.save()` fails. Django will throw an exception. You shouldn't worry about it. but you can try performing a filter request and see if the object is created. (but it's not recommended. it will cause an additional DB hit)

Comment: firstly you should check your query on the view (maybe some filter on the query caused that), the best way to check your data exist, you can perform a DB query on the Django shell / or run a SQL query on the DB server. after you to be sure about your data existence, you should focus on your view logic.

Comment: also, did you do debug on your ReportListView? are u sure is the form you submitted is valid?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I can confirm that saving IS working. My database is sqlite3. Seems like an issue with my query. Do you know how to stop execution to print some values in the browser?

Comment: if you're using an ide, you can use your ide's debugging tool (this is the cleanest way) otherwise you can write `breakpoint()` below the line you want to stop the execution. The third and last way using the `ipdb` package.